# Update JSONB with UUID value

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with a column of jsonb type, the JSON object is of key:value pairs, the problem is, I need to update one of the keys to contain a UUID instead of the original value.

The update statement I'm using:

```
UPDATE
    public.applications a
SET
    data = jsonb_set(data, '{id}', (SELECT b.uuid FROM public.devices b WHERE b.id = (a.data ->> 'id')::integer)::text)
```

Postgres returns the following error:

```
ERROR:  function jsonb_set(jsonb, unknown, text) does not exist
```

I've tried to cast the value to different data types, but with same result.

**Sample data**

```
id | data
---------
1  | {"id": 1}
2  | {"id": 2}
```

**Expected output**

```
id | data
---------
1  | {"id": device_uuid_here}
2  | {"id": device_uuid_here}
```

DB_VERSION: PostgreSQL12.12

Comment: Can you share sample tables and expected output?

Comment: Updated question with required info.

Comment: `jsonb_set` was introduced in Postgres 9.5. Maybe you're using an older version?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 12.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE public.applications a
SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{id}', 
  (SELECT '"'||b.uuid::text||'"' FROM public.devices b 
  WHERE b.id = (a.data ->> 'id')::integer)::jsonb);
```

Comment: Great, it works! could you explain why?